# Can't get to Property Settings in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I can't access anything under Property Settings in Google Analytics admin.  It's just greyed out with no options underneath so I can't update my url or get tracking code.  Does anyone know why or what to do?  I have been trying for months but can't find any advice on this online; all of the instructions to do what I need to do start with 'click on Property Settings' which I can do.  Why is it unavailable/how do I resolve it?  I have a Universal Analytics property.  Are there companies who can help with GA problems (presumably not google obviously!)

Comment: Julia, welcome to StackOverflow. Sometimes a screenshot could help to understand the issue. The "Create Property" button is greyed out and everything underneath? No any property added yet? Maybe user permissions? Under Account column->Account User Management->Your user->tick the Edit checkbox->Save->Reload the page. This disables/enables 'Create Property' button for me.

Comment: Actually this google support page on Editing Property mentions Edit permissions https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3467852?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works, but I clicked "create new property" and created a new property.

I accidentally created 4 (no idea how), so I had to delete everything except for the one I needed.

Then, for some reasons I have "property settings" for the one I need

Google's functionality is some kind of magic for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32081797)